# Al implementar herencia al struct Consulta, El error dice no matching funtion for call, apunta a los constructores

Tags: c++, herencia

Quitando el :public Paciente ( la herencia) el código compila y los constructores no parecen tener problemas. En el main los parámetros para cada objeto funcionan. Aquello que puedan explicarme para solucionar este error puede que me dé mayor comprensión sobre lo que sucede al implementar la herencia y sobre la inicialización de constructores.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Paciente{
private:
string apellido;
string nombres;
string documento;
string obraSocial;

public:
Paciente(string apellido, 
string nombres, string 
documento, string 
obraSocial   );

void mostrarPaciente();


};

struct Consulta   {
string sintomas, 
examenes, diagnostico;  

public:

Consulta(string sintomas, 
string examenes, string 
diagnostco);

void mostrarConsulta();
}; 

struct HistMedico{

vector <string> c1;



};



int main() {

Paciente 
m17896543("Gonzalez", 
"Juan Carlos","17896543", 
"Osde");
m17896543 
.mostrarPaciente ();
 Consulta f121221("Dolor de  Garganta ", 
"Observacion clinica", 
"Placas");

f121221 . mostrarConsulta 
();
m17896543 
.mostrarPaciente ();

 return 0;
}

Paciente::Paciente(string 
m_apellido, string 
m_nombres, string 
m_documento, string 
m_obraSocial )
:apellido {m_apellido}, 
nombres {m_nombres 
},documento {m_documento 
}, obraSocial { 
m_obraSocial }

{
 cout<<"Construyendo".
<<endl ; 
cout<<  m_apellido 
<<endl;

}

void Paciente:: 
mostrarPaciente(){


cout<<"...…........."
<<endl;
cout<<apellido<<" "
<<nombres<<" "
<<documento<<" "
<<obraSocial<<endl;
 
 

             }

Consulta :: Consulta 
(string m_sintomas, 
string m_examenes, string 
m_diagnostico)
: sintomas 
{m_sintomas},examenes{ 
m_examenes}, diagnostico 
{m_diagnostico}

 {
 cout<< "Grabando 
 consulta"<< endl ;   
 
 } 

 void Consulta:: 
 mostrarConsulta (){
 
 cout<< sintomas<<" "
 <<examenes<<" "
 <<diagnostico<<endl;   
 
 
 
 }
```

Son dos structs diferentes debido a la intención final de separar los datos del cliente del diagnóstico médico tratando de preservar el anonimato de éste último y a la vez pensando en poder adjuntarle de algún modo, varias consultas a un mismo paciente.  El compilador se queja de los constructores apenas intento mostrar Paciente y Consulta juntos en éste código.

Comment: El código no compila porque hay ciertos caracteres donde no debería haberlos, si se quitan todos los disparates que hay en código original compila sin mostrar el error que mencionas en el título. ¿Cuál es el problema? Por favor, se más específico y muestra un ejemplo del problema que estás encontrando.

Comment: Soy autodidacta y sólo es una práctica para practicar herencia y el modo de implementar constructores. Preparé dos struct y los instancié pero al heredarlo ya no funcionó.. Trataré de deducir los caracteres que no están dónde deben. Mi duda fué por qué a partir de la herencia dejó de compilar, qué es lo que cambió....por qué esos caracteres antes no eran un problema?

Comment: Busqué los caracteres disparates: no son el endl, ni los " ", ni string , ni los m_. Tampoco son las llaves {} ( las reemplacé por paréntesis y por el =)...por descarte...no lo veo

Comment: Los disparates son poner un punto (`.`) después de un literal de texto (`" "`)  en las llamadas a `std::cout`, por ejemplo `cout<<"...….........". `. Otro disparate es separar un literal de texto en dos líneas sin cerrar el literal en cada línea como por ejemplo `"Dolor` en una línea y `de  Garganta "` en otra. Si no podemos compilar tu código y tu código no muestra el comportamiento que describes: NO PODREMOS ayudarte.

Comment: Agradecido por tu atención a este post. Los errores que marcas son oportunos. Ellos no estaban en el código original, al editar la pregunta sucedió y como programo desde el celular no los ví. La frase del cout en dos renglones la divide el editor al agregar los 4 espacios q requiere el código. Ya edité la pregunta tratando de explicarme mejor. En tanto el código no compile lo uso como oportunidad para repasar constructores

Comment: El código sigue teniendo errores como los que describí antes, y el código compila y se ejecuta perfectamente al contrario de lo que dices. No entiendo tu pregunta. Si tu código no muestra el comportamiento que describes: NO PODREMOS ayudarte.

Comment: Cierto, tenía un error más de esos que ya corregí en la edición del código y compila. Llevaba días bloqueado en eso. No tengo cómo agradecerte, sólo no hubiera hallado esos errores. Compila!

Answer (score 0):

Por el error que dice tiene, puedo deducir que no estan implementados los costructores de la clase que heredo Paciente. Por ejemplo:

Si tiene esa struct con ese constrcutor, y desea usarla para herencia de otra.

```
struct Paciente{
private:
...

public:
Paciente(string apellido, string nombres, string documento, string obraSocial);
...
};
```

En esa nueva clase debe implementar un costructor similar al de este ejemplo:

```
struct Consulta: public Paciente {
    Consulta(string apellido, string nombres, string documento, string obraSocial) 
        : Paciente(apelldiom nombres, documento, obraSocial) {

    }
}
```

Con eso el struct hijo podra hacer uso del Constructor del struct padre e inicializar las variables heredaras del padre. Tambien si desea que el struct hijo pueda hacer uso de los atributos privados de la clase padre, lo mejor es que las ponga como protected en vez de private. [Aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-c/) podra ver informacion mas detallada respecto a la henrecia en C++.

Comment: Agradezco su tiempo. Ya probé pasando los datos a protected y no hubo cambio. También intenté usar un sólo constructor . Había intentado leer las variables heredadas (como protected)en el constructor del struct hijo sin resultado. Pero puede que deba seguir intentando por ese camino, pude hacerlo mal ( Incluso implementé apellido= m_apellido en lugar de apellido {m_apellido} y tampoco es eso). Revisaré  y leeré la documentación q me propone en el link para aclarar dudas y tratar de hallar solución. De momento, sólo quitando herencia el código funciona. Agradecido